# TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not callable when appending line to csv file

Tags: python, csv, append

While trying to append a line to a csv file I am getting the following error message and can't understand what is wrong.

*TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not callable*

This snippet of code works in ipynb, but not when I try to run the entire code. This is my code: Thanks in advance!

```
import os
from csv import writer
curr_game = 'Catan'
curr_game_filename = curr_game + '.csv'
path = r'D:\Python\Ratings\History'

with open(os.path.join(path, curr_game_filename), 'a', newline='') as gamehistory:
    listtoappend = ['Playername', 'Eva', 'Louis', 'Jean']
    writer_object = writer(gamehistory)
    writer_object.writerow(listtoappend)
    gamehistory.close()
```

Comment: Can you include the full traceback? And what is `writer`? Was there a `from csv import writer`?

Comment: Please include enough code to allow people to recreate your problem, that means all `import` statements, full variable declarations, etc, AKA [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, i forget to add, question is now edited

Comment: Your code, as-is, works and doesn't produce errors. Is there more code than this? Can you show the full traceback of what you're seeing?